# Cant't deploy after update new version parseconsole.exe

Tags: deployment, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

today I've updated my parseconsole.exe and I can't deploy my code when yesterday I could.

I've try to do another develop but the same error happens, this is the trace:

```
> parse new WebContent
Creating directory C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works_pars
e_luna\Prueba_node\WebContent\config
Creating config file C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works_pa
rse_luna\Prueba_node\WebContent\config\global.json
Creating directory C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works_pars
e_luna\Prueba_node\WebContent\cloud
Writing out sample file C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works
_parse_luna\Prueba_node\WebContent\cloud\main.js
Creating directory C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works_pars
e_luna\Prueba_node\WebContent\public
Writing out sample file C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works
_parse_luna\Prueba_node\WebContent\public\index.html
Email: xxxxxx
Password:
1: prueba
2: prueba_cloud
Select an App: 2
PS C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works_parse_luna\Prueba_no
de> cd WebContent
PS C:\Users\NOTEBOOK\Documents\docs\Parse\Works_parse_luna\Prueba_no
de\WebContent> parse deploy
Uploading source files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\main", line 695, in main
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\main", line 206, in handle_deploy
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\parse", line 332, in deploy
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\parse", line 231, in upload_source
_files
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\parse", line 39, in post
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 126, in urlopen
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 391, in open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 409, in _open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 369, in _call_chain
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 1178, in https_open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 1142, in do_open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib", line 914, in request
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib", line 954, in _send_request
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib", line 759, in send
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 203, in sendall
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 174, in send
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray
```

thaks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there is a new version that is working.

Parse CLI v3.0.2

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/releases/

Answer (score 0):

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/26982677/2211980, it seems that Parse has released a new version. I've just downloaded it from: https://www.parse.com/downloads/windows/console/parse.zip.

There is a deprecated warning but after seeing exactly the same errors as yours yesterday, I can now deploy, thankfully.

Comment: The only solution I found, it was come back the last parseconsole.exe

Comment: That's odd - I have been using the newest version with no issues (other than the deprecation warning) since the 19th. Stupid questions but have you deleted everything and tried again, just to make sure?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but it may help newcomers in the future,

Parse announed that they made a change that require everyone to manually download the **newest** version of their CLI as of today (7.2.2015) the current version is **2.1.2** you can download it directly from the [Parse.com](http://Parse%20website)

or if you like I made a repo containing the files for it, [CLI Repo](https://github.com/JRSosa/ParseCLI)

Hope it helps.