# Parse Cloud Code deploy not possible

Tags: json, parse-platform

i hope you can help me handle this. I downloaded the newest version of ParseConsole.exe for Windows and tried to deploy my cloudcode which was generated by parse new. 
Thats the error send by the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\main", line 695, in main
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\main", line 206, in handle_deploy
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\parse", line 332, in deploy
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\parse", line 231, in upload_sourc
_files
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\parse", line 39, in post
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 126, in urlopen
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 391, in open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 409, in _open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 369, in _call_chai

  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 1178, in https_ope

  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\urllib2", line 1142, in do_open
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib", line 914, in request
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib", line 954, in _send_requ
st
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib", line 759, in send
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 203, in sendall
  File ".\build\pyi.win32\parse\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 174, in send
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray
```

I hope you can help. I tried to add other versions in my global.json file but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: i already added the newest version of python! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started happening to me too after upgrading to version 1.3.3 (from 1.3.0)

I am using a Windows machine so I cannot upgrade python, I think it's embedded in the exe or something like that.

It's very annoying since it worked before with the version I had!

Very unprofessional.. I hope they will solve it soon.

**Update:**

Version 1.3.4 is now available for Windows but it still does not work.. trying to deploy I get the message

> Update failed with internal error

**Update 2:**

It seems to work now... I am not sure if they fix something on their side. It says version 1.3.4 is deprecated buy my guess is that it just a bug with checking the versions.

Answer (score 0):

You must update parse CLI to its latest version **2.1.2**, you can do it directly from **[Parse.com](http://www.parse.com)**.

I created a repository in GitHub to make it easier,

https://github.com/JRSosa/ParseCLI